# Are there any luggage lockers in Yangon (Rangoon)?

Tags: luggage-storage, myanmar

My flight arrives to Yangon at 10:00 and I want to go directly to Mandalay this night by train. Normally when I do something like this I leave my backpack at the train station or somewhere else, but in this case I cannot find any information about luggage lockers in the station or other places in Yangon. Are there any?

Comment: I find mention of luggage storage in the airport which would be inconvenient for you or you might want to ask a hostel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The consensus online seems to be that, at the time of writing, there are no luggage lockers around Yangon. Your best bet would be to **ask a hotel to keep the luggage for you**. They will most probably ask for a fee. Even better would be to leave your luggage in a hotel where you plan on staying once you come back to Yangon, if applicable. Other options include [hire a car with driver for the day and leave the luggage in there](https://www.tripadvisor.com.ph/ShowTopic-g294191-i9454-k7954604-Left_luggage_in_Yangon-Yangon_Rangoon_Yangon_Region.html), and [leaving your luggage at the bus station ticket counter](https://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/forums/asia-south-east-asia-mainland/myanmar/is-there-any-luggage-storage-at-yangon-downtown-direct-bus-to-inle). Both options will cost you.

Comment: Yes, there are no public place where we can left our luggage. We asked at the train station and they said that we cannot leave anything there.